# Magento block template has different positions in the right sidebar depending on the page

Tags: magento, facebook-likebox

My goal is to place Facebook like box above "Recently Viewed Product" section in the right sidebar. To accomplish this I put the following lines into local․xml․

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="core/template" name="socialsharing"
          template="social/facebooklikebox.phtml"
          before="right.reports.product.viewed" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

But accidentally I found that in some pages Facebook like box is placed below "Recently Viewed Product".
I can't find out the reason of this behaviour.

**UPDATE:**

> When I removed "right.reports.product.viewed" block I realized that in some pages "Recently Viewed Product" is still existed. So I understood that some pages are displayed with "Recently Viewed Product" using "right.reports.product.viewed" and some using "left.reports.product.viewed".

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: add after="socialsharing" into "Recently Viewed Product" and check.

Comment: Thanks, I try but it doesn't work. When I removed  "right.reports.product.viewed" block I realized that in some pages "Recently Viewed Product" is still existed. So I understood on some pages display "Recently Viewed Product" with "right.reports.product.viewed" and some with  "left.reports.product.viewed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have got the answer how to put "Facebook Like Box" above "Recently Viewed Product" in all pages:

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="core/template" name="socialsharing"
          template="social/facebooklikebox.phtml"
          before="left.reports.product.viewed" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

In my case it was necessary to use 'before="left.reports.product.viewed"' instead of 'before="right.reports.product.viewed"'.

Unfortunately, I still don't know the reason of behavior mentioned in the "UPDATE" section of the question.